# How set name to automatically launched instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I use bat file to launch Amazon Instances by this code: 
`ec2-run-instances %AMI_Id% -k ED_Key_Pair -t t1.micro -g default -z us-east-1a`

But I can not set name of the Instances. I want use 
`ec2-create-tags resource_id [resource_id ...] --tag key[=value] [--tag key[=value] ...]` command to set a name. But I can not get  `Instances ID` from remote computer. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance id should be returned by the `ec2-run-instances` command. A part of the returned string should be something like:

```
INSTANCE    <instance_id>
```

instance_id should be in the format `i-12345678`

If you are on windows (cmd) you will most likely also need to wrap your key=[value] in double quotes.

```
ec2-create-tags i-12345678 "key=value"
```

or in Powershell

```
ec2-create-tags i-12345678 `"key=value`"
```

Comment: The -t switch is missing. It should be:

    ec2-create-tags i-12345678 -t "key=value"